# How to make slicer affect only one table on the same page in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

When changing the slicer from **"All"** to a specific selection, it changes both tables that are on the same page. I would like it to only filter through a specific table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to configure the interactions of the slicer and the other visuals on the page. To do that, select the slicer, then go to Format > Edit interactions. Now all visuals show with a few icons on the top right corner. Select what interaction you want.

For more detail see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/service-reports-visual-interactions